# Parse Server Saving Images with Android Not Working

Tags: android, image, parse-platform, parse-server

I am trying to upload an image to my parse server on AWS and mongoLab. However whenever I try to add the image with the code below, I got an error, when I try to save the object without the image, it succeeds. Am I doing something wrong. I am trying for more than 10 hours and could not make it work.

```
ParseFile image1;

Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
        R.drawable.ph);

ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

image1 = new ParseFile("profilePhoto.png", byteArray);
image1.saveInBackground();


JSONArray myFriendList = new JSONArray();
myFriendList.put("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
myFriendList.put("yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy");

ParseObject userSettingObj = new ParseObject("userSetting");
userSettingObj.put("profileName", profileNameField.getText().toString());
userSettingObj.put("userid", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
userSettingObj.put("name", nameField.getText().toString());
userSettingObj.put("surname", surnameField.getText().toString());
userSettingObj.put("friendList", myFriendList);

userSettingObj.put("photo", image1);

userSettingObj.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {

        if (e == null) {

            System.out.println("saved successfully");

        } else {

            System.out.println("error while saving");

        }

    }
});
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Call your _SaveCallback_  for your  _ParseFile_  instead of _ParseObject_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and let me know.

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
image1 = new ParseFile("profilePhoto.png", byteArray);
image1.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {

            if (e == null) {
    upload();
            } else {

            }

        }
    });

    public void upload(){
JSONArray myFriendList = new JSONArray();
    myFriendList.put("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    myFriendList.put("yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy");

    ParseObject userSettingObj = new ParseObject("userSetting");
    userSettingObj.put("profileName",    profileNameField.getText().toString());
    userSettingObj.put("userid", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
    userSettingObj.put("name", nameField.getText().toString());
    userSettingObj.put("surname", surnameField.getText().toString());
    userSettingObj.put("friendList", myFriendList);

    userSettingObj.put("photo", byteArray);

    userSettingObj.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {

            if (e == null) {

                System.out.println("saved successfully");

            } else {

                System.out.println("error while saving");

            }

        }
    });}
```

Comment: Hello Alex, nope, still note working, how can I understand the error?

Comment: No, still not, but the upload() function is not starting, the error is in the file saving part. In the first saveCallBack it goes to the error part.

Comment: I guess it is a bug in parseServer that is mentioned in the link: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/136

Comment: When you add context to the parseFile creation, it starts to work as below: image1 = new ParseFile("profilePhoto.png", byteArray, "image/png"); it is a bug of the parseServer which is fixed in next releases. Thank you very much Alex.

Comment: Ohhh! I was offline for sometime,Thats y i didnt seen ur msgs. Anyway, nice to hear that this leaded you in correct way. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally after few hours effort I am able to upload a Parse file on Parse DataBase
   Steps To Follow: 
   1 - Write a SignUp Query First.
   2 - On Successful response of SignUp Query you will get a Current User Object Id.
   3-  Then Create One Custom Class in Parse database "profilePictureTable" and add Certain Columns 1- profilePicture. 2- userObjectId.
  4- Then Finally Call Callback SaveInBackground

[image: Sample Image that how it will look a like]

```
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("Your File Path");
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    final byte[] data = stream.toByteArray();


    final ParseFile file = new ParseFile("profile_pic.png", data);

    file.saveInBackground();

    final ParseObject profilePicture = new ParseObject("profilePictureTable");
    profilePicture.put("profilePicture", file);
    profilePicture.put("userObjectId",ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());

    profilePicture.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e)
        {
            if (e == null)
            {
                Log.i("Parse", "saved successfully");


            }
            else
            {
                Log.i("Parse", "error while saving");
            }
        }
    });
```